# Numpy average and nanmean of 1-dimensional array returns multiple values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

my larger project involves finding the average distance between two contours, but the part of the problem I'm having an issue with involves something much simpler -- both `np.average` and `np.nanmean` are returning multiple values for very short 1-dimensional arrays. See below for the example code and output: this part of the code just checks for nearby points between two subsets of contour coordinates, averages over the nearby points if there are multiple, and appends the new values into a new array.

```
for i in range(5):
    print('i=',i)
    c131x_1_idx=np.where((smoothed_c131y_1 > c193y_1[i]) & 
                         (smoothed_c131y_1 < c193y_1[i]+c193y_diff_avg))
    c131x_1_idx=c131x_1_idx[0]
    print("c131x_1_idx=",c131x_1_idx)
    c131x_1_temp=[]
    if c131x_1_idx.size > 0:
        for j in range(len(c131x_1_idx)):
            c131x_1_temp.append(smoothed_c131x_1[c131x_1_idx[j]])
        print(c131x_1_temp)
        avg131x_1.append(np.nanmean(c131x_1_temp))
        print(avg131x_1)
        avg131x_1_diff.append(avg131x_1-c193x_1[i])
    if c131x_1_idx.size == 0:
        avg131x_1_diff.append(np.NAN)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
i= 0
c131x_1_idx= []
i= 1
c131x_1_idx= []
i= 2
c131x_1_idx= [1]
[<Quantity -59.39999836>]
[-59.39999835782995]
i= 3
c131x_1_idx= []
i= 4
c131x_1_idx= [3 6]
[<Quantity -59.39999836>, <Quantity -58.48333177>]
[-59.39999835782995, -58.941665061943546]
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting multiple values for the last value in the loop? Thank you in advance!

Comment: When i=2 you append [-59.39999835782995] to `avg131x_1`. When i=4, you're APPENDING the average to `avg131x_1` so you should expect to have two values.

Comment: @not_speshal Wow, I should have seen that...thank you so much, this was the last bug holding up a deadline!